# How to clear localStorage using selenium and webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python, web-application

I want to call localStorage.clear() before running a group of specific tests but the thing is I don't know how. I can see CLEAR_LOCAL_STORAGE variable mentioned
 [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.command.html) but still failing to understand where exactly this constant is used and how I can perform desired action.

If calling js execution is the only option I'm OK with it but the existence of this constant makes me looking for a better solution.

Comment: Why you feel you need to clear LocalStore? Selenium will give you new instance of browser with nothing in store or anywhere. Is it business requirement or just your hunch?

Comment: @PeterMasiar - to my knowledge it's not true - are you 100% sure that localStorage is cleared?

Comment: If you get new instance of the browser, it should get new local storage, IIUC. No cache. It took 40 secs to build new instance of Firefox until recently. I haven't checked localStore.

Comment: @PeterMasiar thanks, this is actually very important, should double check.

Comment: I have confirmed by testing both the Firefox and Chrome drivers, that upon instantiating the driver, the browser's localStorage is empty. This is true even when another instance of the same browser is already open in another window. My environment is Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7.6, Selenium 2.44.0.

Answer (score 12):

If your driver implements `WebStorage` you can invoke

```
driver.getSessionStorage().clear();
driver.getLocalStorage().clear();
```

In order to make sure that the driver does implement `WebStorage` the idiom is

```
if (driver instanceof WebStorage) {
    WebStorage webStorage = (WebStorage)driver;
    webStorage.getSessionStorage().clear();
    webStorage.getLocalStorage().clear();
}
```

or better

```
if (!(driver instanceof WebStorage)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("This test expects the driver to implement WebStorage");
}
WebStorage webStorage = (WebStorage)driver;
webStorage.getSessionStorage().clear();
webStorage.getLocalStorage().clear();
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer Peter Masiar gave no longer works. This answer will result in the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in get
>       self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unsupported protocol
>     (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.3 x86_64)

In order to clear the `localStorage` the `execute_script()` method from `WebDriver` should be used.

```
WebDriver.execute_script('window.localStorage.clear();')
```

Answer (score 3):

After you `driver.get(URL)` to your page, you can execute javascript in it from webdriver, like this

`driver.get('javascript:<your JS snippet here>')`

so try

`driver.get('javascript:localStorage.clear();')`

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the current way to do this is:

```csharp
if (driver.HasWebStorage) {
   driver.WebStorage.LocalStorage.Clear();
}
else {
   // you're out of luck...
}
```

**Update (Selenium 4)**

In Selenium 4, `HasWebStorage` and `WebStorage` are marked as obsolete:

```
[CS0618] 'WebDriver.HasWebStorage' is obsolete: 'Use JavaScript instead
for managing localStorage and sessionStorage. This property will be removed 
in a future release.'
```

It looks like the intended way is now:

```csharp
if ((bool?)driver.ExecuteScript("return !!window.localStorage") == true) {
    driver.ExecuteScript("window.localStorage.clear();");
}
```